# How to find methods with only one usage in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

With the intention of cleaning up code, I am searching for methods with only one usage, to inline them. Is there any way to find them, other than manually?

Comment: There's very little benefit to inlining methods, and it will almost certainly hurt readability.

Comment: Some would argue that's the opposite of cleaning up code. It's better to have descriptive identifiers for your logic, makes code easier to read.